# Fit Lasso with SCAD penalty without an intercept

Tags: r, cross-validation, non-linear-regression, lasso-regression

I am using `cv.ncvreg` fit `Lasso` with `SCAD`. Since I need to select `lambda` using cross validation, therefore I opt to use `cv.ncvreg` function. I have given my `r` codes below.

```
library(ncvreg)
n = 100
p = 10
beta0 = c(2, 0, 3, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0)
X = matrix(rnorm(n * p, 0,1), ncol = p)
y=vector(mode="numeric",length=n) 
X[,3]=rnorm(n,2,1)
X[,4]=rnorm(n,4,1)
X[,5]=rnorm(n,5,1)
ei_N=rnorm(n,0,1)   # the model errors 
y= X%*%beta0 + ei_N
fit = cv.ncvreg(X, y, penalty = "SCAD", standardize=TRUE)
coef = coef(fit, s = "lambda.min")
coef
```

I obtain the following output

```
(Intercept)          V1          V2          V3          V4          V5          V6          V7 
 0.06907783  1.98544923  0.00000000  3.01165615  0.00000000  0.00000000  1.00447815  0.00000000 
         V8          V9         V10 
 0.00000000  0.00000000  0.00000000
```

If you see the output, the fitted model has an `intercept`. How can I fit `lasso` with `SCAD` penalty without an `intercept` while cross validation to select `lambda`? Thank you.

Comment: Don't think its possible with the package. See https://github.com/pbreheny/ncvreg/issues/6

Comment: @JonnyPhelps, Thanks. I tried using `glmnet`. But I cannot use `scad` penalty over there.